# Display black background overlay around ploygon shape on bingmaps

Tags: bing-maps

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=experimental&callback=loadMapScenario' async defer></script>
        <title>setPolygonRingsHTML</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
</head>
<body>

    <div id='printoutPanel'></div>

    <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:750px; height:450px;"></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        function loadMapScenario() {
            var js_array = [[new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.708909801732, -122.33284698829), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.708909801732, -122.32996277166), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.708909801732, -122.32707855502), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.706137489184, -122.32419433839), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.703365176637, -122.32419433839), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.701979020363, -122.32563644671), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.70059286409, -122.32419433839), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.70059286409, -122.32275223007), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.697820551542, -122.31986801343), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.696434395269, -122.31842590512), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.695048238995, -122.31842590512), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.695048238995, -122.3169837968), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.693662082721, -122.31554168848), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.693662082721, -122.31409958016), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.692275926447, -122.31265747185), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.692275926447, -122.31121536353), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.690889770174, -122.30977325521), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.690889770174, -122.30833114689), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.692275926447, -122.30688903858), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.690889770174, -122.30544693026), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.6895036139, -122.30688903858), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.686731301353, -122.30400482194), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.685345145079, -122.30400482194), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.683958988805, -122.30544693026), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.682572832531, -122.30544693026), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.681186676258, -122.30400482194), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.67841436371, -122.30400482194), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.675642051163, -122.30400482194), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.674255894889, -122.30256271362), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.672869738616, -122.30256271362), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.671483582342, -122.30112060531), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.670097426068, -122.30112060531), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.668711269794, -122.29967849699), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.665938957247, -122.29967849699), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.664552800973, -122.29823638867), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.6631666447, -122.29823638867), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.660394332152, -122.29535217203), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.660394332152, -122.2924679554), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.660394332152, -122.28958373876), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.660394332152, -122.28814163045), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.659008175879, -122.28669952213), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.659008175879, -122.28381530549), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.657622019605, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.657622019605, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.656235863331, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.656235863331, -122.27804687222), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.654849707057, -122.27660476391), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.654849707057, -122.27516265559), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.653463550784, -122.27372054727), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.653463550784, -122.27083633063), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.653463550784, -122.26939422232), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.65207739451, -122.267952114), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.65207739451, -122.26651000568), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.649305081963, -122.26362578905), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.646532769415, -122.26074157241), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.646532769415, -122.25785735578), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.646532769415, -122.25497313914), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.643760456868, -122.2520889225), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.642374300594, -122.25064681419), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.639601988047, -122.25064681419), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.638215831773, -122.25064681419), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.635443519226, -122.25353103082), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.635443519226, -122.25497313914), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.634057362952, -122.25641524746), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.634057362952, -122.25929946409), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.634057362952, -122.26218368073), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.635443519226, -122.26362578905), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.635443519226, -122.26506789736), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.634057362952, -122.26651000568), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.634057362952, -122.267952114), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.632671206678, -122.26939422232), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.632671206678, -122.27227843895), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.632671206678, -122.27516265559), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.632671206678, -122.27804687222), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.632671206678, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.632671206678, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.631285050404, -122.28381530549), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.629898894131, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.628512737857, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.627126581583, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.624354269036, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.622968112762, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.620195800215, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.617423487667, -122.27660476391), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.61465117512, -122.27660476391), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.613265018846, -122.27516265559), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.611878862573, -122.27660476391), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.610492706299, -122.27516265559), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.607720393751, -122.27516265559), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.604948081204, -122.27516265559), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.604948081204, -122.27372054727), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.60356192493, -122.27227843895), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.60356192493, -122.27083633063), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.602175768657, -122.26939422232), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.602175768657, -122.267952114), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.599403456109, -122.26506789736), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.596631143562, -122.26218368073), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.596631143562, -122.25929946409), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.598017299835, -122.25785735578), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.598017299835, -122.25497313914), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.598017299835, -122.2520889225), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.598017299835, -122.25064681419), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.596631143562, -122.24920470587), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.596631143562, -122.24776259755), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.593858831014, -122.24487838092), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.593858831014, -122.2434362726), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.595244987288, -122.24199416428), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.595244987288, -122.23910994765), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.595244987288, -122.23622573101), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.592472674741, -122.23334151438), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.591086518467, -122.23189940606), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.589700362193, -122.23334151438), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.58831420592, -122.23334151438), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.586928049646, -122.23478362269), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.586928049646, -122.23622573101), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.585541893372, -122.23766783933), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.585541893372, -122.24055205596), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.586928049646, -122.24199416428), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.586928049646, -122.2434362726), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.585541893372, -122.2434362726), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.584155737098, -122.24487838092), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.584155737098, -122.24632048923), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.581383424551, -122.24920470587), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.581383424551, -122.2520889225), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.581383424551, -122.25497313914), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.581383424551, -122.25785735578), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.581383424551, -122.25929946409), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.582769580825, -122.26074157241), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.582769580825, -122.26218368073), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.579997268277, -122.26506789736), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.579997268277, -122.26651000568), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.57722495573, -122.26939422232), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.57722495573, -122.27227843895), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.575838799456, -122.27372054727), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.575838799456, -122.27660476391), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.575838799456, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.574452643182, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.574452643182, -122.28381530549), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.575838799456, -122.28525741381), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.575838799456, -122.28814163045), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.575838799456, -122.29102584708), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.574452643182, -122.29102584708), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.573066486909, -122.28958373876), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.570294174361, -122.28958373876), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.568908018088, -122.29102584708), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.567521861814, -122.29102584708), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.564749549267, -122.29391006372), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.563363392993, -122.29391006372), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.560591080445, -122.29679428035), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.557818767898, -122.29679428035), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.556432611624, -122.29535217203), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.553660299077, -122.29535217203), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.553660299077, -122.2924679554), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.55088798653, -122.28958373876), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.548115673982, -122.28669952213), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.546729517708, -122.28525741381), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.545343361435, -122.28525741381), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.542571048887, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.53979873634, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.537026423792, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.535640267519, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.532867954971, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.531481798698, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.530095642424, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.52870948615, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.527323329877, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.525937173603, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.524551017329, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.523164861055, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.520392548508, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.519006392234, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.517620235961, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.516234079687, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.513461767139, -122.28381530549), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.512075610866, -122.28525741381), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.512075610866, -122.28814163045), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.512075610866, -122.29102584708), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.513461767139, -122.2924679554), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.513461767139, -122.29391006372), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.514847923413, -122.29535217203), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.516234079687, -122.29535217203), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.516234079687, -122.29679428035), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.519006392234, -122.29967849699), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.521778704782, -122.29967849699), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.521778704782, -122.30112060531), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.524551017329, -122.30400482194), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.527323329877, -122.30688903858), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.527323329877, -122.30833114689), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.530095642424, -122.31121536353), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.530095642424, -122.31409958016), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.531481798698, -122.31554168848), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.531481798698, -122.3169837968), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.534254111245, -122.31986801343), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.535640267519, -122.32131012175), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.537026423792, -122.32131012175), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.538412580066, -122.32275223007), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.538412580066, -122.32563644671), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.53979873634, -122.32707855502), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.53979873634, -122.32996277166), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.542571048887, -122.33284698829), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.542571048887, -122.33428909661), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.545343361435, -122.33717331325), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.546729517708, -122.33717331325), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.548115673982, -122.33861542156), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.548115673982, -122.34005752988), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.55088798653, -122.34294174652), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.55088798653, -122.34438385484), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.553660299077, -122.34726807147), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.556432611624, -122.35015228811), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.557818767898, -122.35159439642), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.559204924172, -122.35159439642), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.561977236719, -122.35447861306), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.563363392993, -122.35592072138), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.564749549267, -122.35592072138), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.56613570554, -122.35736282969), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.56613570554, -122.36024704633), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.56613570554, -122.36168915465), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.568908018088, -122.36457337128), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.570294174361, -122.3660154796), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.571680330635, -122.3660154796), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.573066486909, -122.36457337128), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.574452643182, -122.36457337128), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.575838799456, -122.36313126296), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.575838799456, -122.36024704633), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.578611112004, -122.36024704633), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.579997268277, -122.36168915465), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.582769580825, -122.36168915465), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.585541893372, -122.36168915465), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.586928049646, -122.36024704633), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.589700362193, -122.36024704633), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.591086518467, -122.36024704633), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.592472674741, -122.35880493801), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.593858831014, -122.35880493801), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.595244987288, -122.35736282969), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.598017299835, -122.35736282969), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.600789612383, -122.36024704633), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.600789612383, -122.36313126296), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.602175768657, -122.36457337128), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.602175768657, -122.3660154796), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.604948081204, -122.36889969624), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.604948081204, -122.37034180455), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.607720393751, -122.37322602119), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.609106550025, -122.37466812951), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.609106550025, -122.37611023782), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.611878862573, -122.37899445446), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.61465117512, -122.38187867109), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.616037331394, -122.38187867109), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.617423487667, -122.38332077941), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.620195800215, -122.38332077941), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.622968112762, -122.38332077941), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.624354269036, -122.38332077941), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.62574042531, -122.38187867109), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.627126581583, -122.38187867109), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.629898894131, -122.38476288773), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.632671206678, -122.38476288773), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.634057362952, -122.38332077941), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.635443519226, -122.38332077941), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.636829675499, -122.38187867109), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.636829675499, -122.38043656278), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.638215831773, -122.37899445446), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.638215831773, -122.37611023782), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.638215831773, -122.37322602119), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.638215831773, -122.37034180455), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.636829675499, -122.36889969624), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.636829675499, -122.3660154796), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.639601988047, -122.36313126296), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.639601988047, -122.36024704633), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.64098814432, -122.35880493801), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.642374300594, -122.35880493801), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.643760456868, -122.35736282969), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.645146613141, -122.35736282969), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.647918925689, -122.35447861306), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.649305081963, -122.35303650474), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.649305081963, -122.35159439642), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.650691238236, -122.35303650474), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.65207739451, -122.35303650474), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.654849707057, -122.35015228811), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.654849707057, -122.34871017979), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.656235863331, -122.34726807147), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.654849707057, -122.34582596315), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.654849707057, -122.34438385484), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.657622019605, -122.34726807147), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.659008175879, -122.34871017979), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.661780488426, -122.34871017979), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.6631666447, -122.34871017979), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.665938957247, -122.34582596315), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.668711269794, -122.34294174652), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.671483582342, -122.34294174652), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.672869738616, -122.3414996382), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.674255894889, -122.3414996382), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.675642051163, -122.34005752988), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.677028207437, -122.34005752988), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.679800519984, -122.33717331325), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.681186676258, -122.33861542156), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.683958988805, -122.33861542156), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.686731301353, -122.33861542156), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.688117457626, -122.33861542156), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.6895036139, -122.34005752988), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.690889770174, -122.34005752988), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.692275926447, -122.33861542156), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.693662082721, -122.34005752988), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.695048238995, -122.34005752988), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.696434395269, -122.33861542156), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.697820551542, -122.33861542156), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.70059286409, -122.33573120493), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.701979020363, -122.33428909661), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.701979020363, -122.33284698829), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.704751332911, -122.33573120493), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.706137489184, -122.33573120493), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.708909801732, -122.33284698829)], [new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.639601988047, -122.2434362726), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.639601988047, -122.24199416428), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.638215831773, -122.24055205596), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.636829675499, -122.24199416428), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.636829675499, -122.2434362726), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.638215831773, -122.24487838092), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.639601988047, -122.2434362726)], [new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.58831420592, -122.22613097279), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.58831420592, -122.22324675615), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.585541893372, -122.22036253952), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.584155737098, -122.22036253952), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.581383424551, -122.22324675615), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.581383424551, -122.22613097279), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.584155737098, -122.22901518942), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.585541893372, -122.22901518942), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.58831420592, -122.22613097279)], [new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.513461767139, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.510689454592, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.509303298318, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.506530985771, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.506530985771, -122.28381530549), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.509303298318, -122.28669952213), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.510689454592, -122.28669952213), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.512075610866, -122.28525741381), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.512075610866, -122.28381530549), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.513461767139, -122.28237319718)], [new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.506530985771, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.505144829497, -122.27804687222), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.503758673224, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.505144829497, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.506530985771, -122.27948898054)]];
            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
                credentials: 'key',
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.6062095, -122.3320708), zoom: 11});
            var polygoncolor = Microsoft.Maps.Color.fromHex('#0ca312');
            var polygon = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(js_array, {fillColor: 'rgba(111,111,111,0.5)', strokeColor: polygoncolor, strokeThickness: 5});
            map.entities.push(polygon);



        }
    </script>

</body>
```

The above code is my polygon shape on bing maps, using this i am getting black color inside the shape but i want the black overlay around the shape like attached image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pUEp.png)

Please help me out to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to create is known as an opacity mask. To do this you need to basically create a polygon of the whole world and cut a hole in it. There is a code sample that does this here: http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#North%20Carolina%20Map

It's actually fairly easy to do with V8. you just need to make the first right in your polygon include the whole world. Here is an updated version of your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>setPolygonRingsHTML</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:750px; height:450px;"></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        function loadMapScenario() {
            var js_array = [[new Microsoft.Maps.Location(-85, -180),new Microsoft.Maps.Location(-85, 180),new Microsoft.Maps.Location(85, 180),new Microsoft.Maps.Location(85, -180)],
            [new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.708909801732, -122.33284698829), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.708909801732, -122.32996277166), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.708909801732, -122.32707855502), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.706137489184, -122.32419433839), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.703365176637, -122.32419433839), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.701979020363, -122.32563644671), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.70059286409, -122.32419433839), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.70059286409, -122.32275223007), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.697820551542, -122.31986801343), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.696434395269, -122.31842590512), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.695048238995, -122.31842590512), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.695048238995, -122.3169837968), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.693662082721, -122.31554168848), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.693662082721, -122.31409958016), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.692275926447, -122.31265747185), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.692275926447, -122.31121536353), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.690889770174, -122.30977325521), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.690889770174, -122.30833114689), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.692275926447, -122.30688903858), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.690889770174, -122.30544693026), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.6895036139, -122.30688903858), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.686731301353, -122.30400482194), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.685345145079, -122.30400482194), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.683958988805, -122.30544693026), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.682572832531, -122.30544693026), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.681186676258, -122.30400482194), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.67841436371, -122.30400482194), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.675642051163, -122.30400482194), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.674255894889, -122.30256271362), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.672869738616, -122.30256271362), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.671483582342, -122.30112060531), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.670097426068, -122.30112060531), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.668711269794, -122.29967849699), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.665938957247, -122.29967849699), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.664552800973, -122.29823638867), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.6631666447, -122.29823638867), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.660394332152, -122.29535217203), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.660394332152, -122.2924679554), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.660394332152, -122.28958373876), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.660394332152, -122.28814163045), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.659008175879, -122.28669952213), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.659008175879, -122.28381530549), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.657622019605, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.657622019605, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.656235863331, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.656235863331, -122.27804687222), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.654849707057, -122.27660476391), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.654849707057, -122.27516265559), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.653463550784, -122.27372054727), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.653463550784, -122.27083633063), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.653463550784, -122.26939422232), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.65207739451, -122.267952114), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.65207739451, -122.26651000568), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.649305081963, -122.26362578905), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.646532769415, -122.26074157241), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.646532769415, -122.25785735578), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.646532769415, -122.25497313914), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.643760456868, -122.2520889225), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.642374300594, -122.25064681419), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.639601988047, -122.25064681419), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.638215831773, -122.25064681419), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.635443519226, -122.25353103082), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.635443519226, -122.25497313914), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.634057362952, -122.25641524746), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.634057362952, -122.25929946409), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.634057362952, -122.26218368073), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.635443519226, -122.26362578905), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.635443519226, -122.26506789736), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.634057362952, -122.26651000568), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.634057362952, -122.267952114), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.632671206678, -122.26939422232), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.632671206678, -122.27227843895), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.632671206678, -122.27516265559), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.632671206678, -122.27804687222), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.632671206678, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.632671206678, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.631285050404, -122.28381530549), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.629898894131, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.628512737857, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.627126581583, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.624354269036, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.622968112762, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.620195800215, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.617423487667, -122.27660476391), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.61465117512, -122.27660476391), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.613265018846, -122.27516265559), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.611878862573, -122.27660476391), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.610492706299, -122.27516265559), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.607720393751, -122.27516265559), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.604948081204, -122.27516265559), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.604948081204, -122.27372054727), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.60356192493, -122.27227843895), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.60356192493, -122.27083633063), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.602175768657, -122.26939422232), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.602175768657, -122.267952114), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.599403456109, -122.26506789736), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.596631143562, -122.26218368073), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.596631143562, -122.25929946409), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.598017299835, -122.25785735578), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.598017299835, -122.25497313914), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.598017299835, -122.2520889225), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.598017299835, -122.25064681419), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.596631143562, -122.24920470587), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.596631143562, -122.24776259755), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.593858831014, -122.24487838092), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.593858831014, -122.2434362726), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.595244987288, -122.24199416428), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.595244987288, -122.23910994765), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.595244987288, -122.23622573101), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.592472674741, -122.23334151438), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.591086518467, -122.23189940606), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.589700362193, -122.23334151438), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.58831420592, -122.23334151438), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.586928049646, -122.23478362269), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.586928049646, -122.23622573101), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.585541893372, -122.23766783933), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.585541893372, -122.24055205596), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.586928049646, -122.24199416428), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.586928049646, -122.2434362726), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.585541893372, -122.2434362726), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.584155737098, -122.24487838092), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.584155737098, -122.24632048923), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.581383424551, -122.24920470587), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.581383424551, -122.2520889225), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.581383424551, -122.25497313914), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.581383424551, -122.25785735578), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.581383424551, -122.25929946409), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.582769580825, -122.26074157241), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.582769580825, -122.26218368073), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.579997268277, -122.26506789736), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.579997268277, -122.26651000568), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.57722495573, -122.26939422232), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.57722495573, -122.27227843895), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.575838799456, -122.27372054727), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.575838799456, -122.27660476391), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.575838799456, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.574452643182, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.574452643182, -122.28381530549), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.575838799456, -122.28525741381), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.575838799456, -122.28814163045), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.575838799456, -122.29102584708), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.574452643182, -122.29102584708), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.573066486909, -122.28958373876), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.570294174361, -122.28958373876), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.568908018088, -122.29102584708), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.567521861814, -122.29102584708), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.564749549267, -122.29391006372), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.563363392993, -122.29391006372), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.560591080445, -122.29679428035), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.557818767898, -122.29679428035), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.556432611624, -122.29535217203), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.553660299077, -122.29535217203), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.553660299077, -122.2924679554), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.55088798653, -122.28958373876), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.548115673982, -122.28669952213), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.546729517708, -122.28525741381), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.545343361435, -122.28525741381), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.542571048887, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.53979873634, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.537026423792, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.535640267519, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.532867954971, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.531481798698, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.530095642424, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.52870948615, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.527323329877, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.525937173603, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.524551017329, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.523164861055, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.520392548508, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.519006392234, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.517620235961, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.516234079687, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.513461767139, -122.28381530549), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.512075610866, -122.28525741381), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.512075610866, -122.28814163045), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.512075610866, -122.29102584708), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.513461767139, -122.2924679554), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.513461767139, -122.29391006372), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.514847923413, -122.29535217203), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.516234079687, -122.29535217203), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.516234079687, -122.29679428035), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.519006392234, -122.29967849699), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.521778704782, -122.29967849699), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.521778704782, -122.30112060531), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.524551017329, -122.30400482194), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.527323329877, -122.30688903858), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.527323329877, -122.30833114689), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.530095642424, -122.31121536353), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.530095642424, -122.31409958016), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.531481798698, -122.31554168848), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.531481798698, -122.3169837968), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.534254111245, -122.31986801343), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.535640267519, -122.32131012175), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.537026423792, -122.32131012175), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.538412580066, -122.32275223007), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.538412580066, -122.32563644671), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.53979873634, -122.32707855502), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.53979873634, -122.32996277166), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.542571048887, -122.33284698829), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.542571048887, -122.33428909661), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.545343361435, -122.33717331325), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.546729517708, -122.33717331325), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.548115673982, -122.33861542156), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.548115673982, -122.34005752988), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.55088798653, -122.34294174652), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.55088798653, -122.34438385484), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.553660299077, -122.34726807147), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.556432611624, -122.35015228811), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.557818767898, -122.35159439642), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.559204924172, -122.35159439642), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.561977236719, -122.35447861306), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.563363392993, -122.35592072138), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.564749549267, -122.35592072138), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.56613570554, -122.35736282969), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.56613570554, -122.36024704633), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.56613570554, -122.36168915465), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.568908018088, -122.36457337128), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.570294174361, -122.3660154796), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.571680330635, -122.3660154796), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.573066486909, -122.36457337128), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.574452643182, -122.36457337128), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.575838799456, -122.36313126296), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.575838799456, -122.36024704633), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.578611112004, -122.36024704633), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.579997268277, -122.36168915465), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.582769580825, -122.36168915465), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.585541893372, -122.36168915465), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.586928049646, -122.36024704633), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.589700362193, -122.36024704633), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.591086518467, -122.36024704633), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.592472674741, -122.35880493801), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.593858831014, -122.35880493801), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.595244987288, -122.35736282969), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.598017299835, -122.35736282969), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.600789612383, -122.36024704633), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.600789612383, -122.36313126296), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.602175768657, -122.36457337128), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.602175768657, -122.3660154796), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.604948081204, -122.36889969624), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.604948081204, -122.37034180455), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.607720393751, -122.37322602119), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.609106550025, -122.37466812951), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.609106550025, -122.37611023782), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.611878862573, -122.37899445446), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.61465117512, -122.38187867109), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.616037331394, -122.38187867109), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.617423487667, -122.38332077941), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.620195800215, -122.38332077941), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.622968112762, -122.38332077941), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.624354269036, -122.38332077941), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.62574042531, -122.38187867109), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.627126581583, -122.38187867109), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.629898894131, -122.38476288773), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.632671206678, -122.38476288773), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.634057362952, -122.38332077941), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.635443519226, -122.38332077941), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.636829675499, -122.38187867109), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.636829675499, -122.38043656278), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.638215831773, -122.37899445446), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.638215831773, -122.37611023782), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.638215831773, -122.37322602119), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.638215831773, -122.37034180455), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.636829675499, -122.36889969624), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.636829675499, -122.3660154796), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.639601988047, -122.36313126296), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.639601988047, -122.36024704633), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.64098814432, -122.35880493801), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.642374300594, -122.35880493801), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.643760456868, -122.35736282969), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.645146613141, -122.35736282969), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.647918925689, -122.35447861306), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.649305081963, -122.35303650474), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.649305081963, -122.35159439642), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.650691238236, -122.35303650474), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.65207739451, -122.35303650474), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.654849707057, -122.35015228811), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.654849707057, -122.34871017979), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.656235863331, -122.34726807147), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.654849707057, -122.34582596315), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.654849707057, -122.34438385484), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.657622019605, -122.34726807147), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.659008175879, -122.34871017979), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.661780488426, -122.34871017979), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.6631666447, -122.34871017979), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.665938957247, -122.34582596315), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.668711269794, -122.34294174652), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.671483582342, -122.34294174652), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.672869738616, -122.3414996382), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.674255894889, -122.3414996382), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.675642051163, -122.34005752988), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.677028207437, -122.34005752988), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.679800519984, -122.33717331325), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.681186676258, -122.33861542156), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.683958988805, -122.33861542156), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.686731301353, -122.33861542156), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.688117457626, -122.33861542156), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.6895036139, -122.34005752988), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.690889770174, -122.34005752988), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.692275926447, -122.33861542156), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.693662082721, -122.34005752988), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.695048238995, -122.34005752988), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.696434395269, -122.33861542156), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.697820551542, -122.33861542156), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.70059286409, -122.33573120493), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.701979020363, -122.33428909661), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.701979020363, -122.33284698829), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.704751332911, -122.33573120493), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.706137489184, -122.33573120493), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.708909801732, -122.33284698829)], 

            [new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.639601988047, -122.2434362726), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.639601988047, -122.24199416428), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.638215831773, -122.24055205596), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.636829675499, -122.24199416428), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.636829675499, -122.2434362726), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.638215831773, -122.24487838092), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.639601988047, -122.2434362726)], 

            [new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.58831420592, -122.22613097279), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.58831420592, -122.22324675615), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.585541893372, -122.22036253952), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.584155737098, -122.22036253952), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.581383424551, -122.22324675615), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.581383424551, -122.22613097279), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.584155737098, -122.22901518942), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.585541893372, -122.22901518942), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.58831420592, -122.22613097279)], 

            [new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.513461767139, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.510689454592, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.509303298318, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.506530985771, -122.28237319718), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.506530985771, -122.28381530549), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.509303298318, -122.28669952213), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.510689454592, -122.28669952213), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.512075610866, -122.28525741381), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.512075610866, -122.28381530549), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.513461767139, -122.28237319718)], 



    [new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.506530985771, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.505144829497, -122.27804687222), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.503758673224, -122.27948898054), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.505144829497, -122.28093108886), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.506530985771, -122.27948898054)]];

        var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
            credentials: 'key',
            center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.6062095, -122.3320708), zoom: 11});
        var polygon = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(js_array, {fillColor: 'rgba(111,111,111,0.5)', strokeColor: '#0ca312', strokeThickness: 5});
        map.entities.push(polygon);
    }
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=experimental&callback=loadMapScenario' async defer>
```